# Editing XML file in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, xml, windows-store-apps

I am working on a Windows Store Application (8.1), and i got confused with XML writing. My code successfully creates XML file in a correct format. However i am not sure how to add new data(new songs) to this xml file and how to edit existing xml file. Long story short, here is my code so far:

```
StorageFolder sf = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("UserInputData", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
StorageFile st = await sf.CreateFileAsync("MusicData.xml", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

var content = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(st);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
{
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(content);
}
else
{
    var root = xmlDoc.CreateElement("music");
    xmlDoc.AppendChild(root);
    var childTag = xmlDoc.CreateElement("song");
    root.AppendChild(childTag);
    var childertag = xmlDoc.CreateElement("name");
    childTag.AppendChild(childertag);
    var childertag2 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("singer");
    childTag.AppendChild(childertag2);
    var childertag3 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("chords");
    childTag.AppendChild(childertag3);
}
await xmlDoc.SaveToFileAsync(st);
```

It is okay to work with non-existent xml file, i just create root and add new elements to this root like this:

```
    XmlText textname = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode("test12");
    childertag.AppendChild(textname);
```

The thing i need help with is, adding new data to xml file which already exists.

I would appreciate your feedback.

My Regards...

Comment: First step, select the element from existing XML document which you want to modify (add new child element, or change element value). Please clarify, you want to add new `<song>` element to existing `<music>`?

Comment: Yes, correct. Like this:
<music>
<song>
<name>Song1</name>
<singer>Singer1</singer>
<chords>test</chords>
</song>
<song>
<name>Song2</name>
<singer>Singer2</singer>
<chords>test2</chords>
</song>
</music>

How can i do selecting the element from exist XML document?

Thanks for reply!

Comment: check my answer, I assumed you only have single `<music>` element in the existing XML..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating new element, you need to select the existing element, for example :

```
var existingRoot = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//music");
```

Then you can do exactly the same way as you did to add new `<song>` element :

```
var childTag = xmlDoc.CreateElement("song");
existingRoot.AppendChild(childTag);
var childertag = xmlDoc.CreateElement("name");
childTag.AppendChild(childertag);
var childertag2 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("singer");
childTag.AppendChild(childertag2);
var childertag3 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("chords");
childTag.AppendChild(childertag3);
```