# Edit XML file in Windows Store app

Tags: c#, xml, windows-store-apps, xmldocument

I am making an app in windows store and having a problem in writing xml in created xml file.
I have followed this **[Editing XML file in Windows Store App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620823/editing-xml-file-in-windows-store-app)** but it didn't work for me.

**I want this xml to be wrote in my xml file on button click.**

**Any alternate way for this stuff..**

```
<drink>
    <drinkImage>ck.png</drinkImage>
    <drinkTitle>COKE</drinkTitle>
    <drinkDescription>(1793-1844)</drinkDescription>
  </drink>
```

my current file is this:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <drinks>
      <drink>
        <drinkImage>pepsi.png</drinkImage>
        <drinkTitle>PEPSI</drinkTitle>
        <drinkDescription>(1793-1844)</drinkDescription>
      </drink>
**<here I Want above xml on button click>**
    </drinks>
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
namespace DrinksApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class coke : Page
    {
        public coke()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

        }
        XmlDocument dom = new XmlDocument();


        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(softdrinks));
        }

        private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
               XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("favourite//fav.xml");
        xmlDoc.Root.Add(new XElement("drink",
                    new XAttribute("drinkImage","ck.png"),
                    new XAttribute("drinkTitle","PEPSI"),
                    new XAttribute("drinkDescription","NONE")

                ));



xmlDoc.Save(xmlDoc); **//This isn't working in windows store ..**
            }



        }




    }
}
```

**I already have an xml file as mentioned above:**
**[image]**

Comment: Is it necessary to use xml? There is more convenient way for storing data in json format.

Comment: actually scenario starts from here.. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34094405/adding-drink-to-favorite-page-on-click-in-windows-store

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrote this in a console app, but it should still work for Windows Store App.

```
      XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("fa.xml");

        xdoc.Root.Add(new XElement("drink",
            new XElement("drinkImage", "Img.png"),
            new XElement("drinkTitle", "NewDrink"),
            new XElement("drinkDescription", "HelloWorld")));

        xdoc.Save("fa.xml");
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<drinks>
  <drink>
    <drinkImage>pepsi.png</drinkImage>
    <drinkTitle>PEPSI</drinkTitle>
    <drinkDescription>(1793-1844)</drinkDescription>
  </drink>
  <drink>
    <drinkImage>Img.png</drinkImage>
    <drinkTitle>NewDrink</drinkTitle>
    <drinkDescription>HelloWorld</drinkDescription>
  </drink>
</drinks>
```

Your original code is very close to what you wanted. You used 'XAttribute' rather than 'XElement'. This isn't a problem but the output would have looked like this...

```
<drink drinkImage="ck.png" drinkTitle="PEPSI" drinkDescription="NONE" />
```

Your actual problem was saving. XDoucment.Save accepts a stream, text writer, xml writer, or string. In this example I used the string path. See more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx

EDIT: Try using a filestream:

```
var xmlFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync("fav.xml");
using (var fileStream = await xmlFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
   xdoc.Save(fileStream);
}
```

Comment: Have mentioned above that **xdoc.Save();**  isn't working in windows store.
while it do works in windows form or console.

Comment: it throws this exception have tried this before..

`An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

WinRT information: The specified path (fav.xml) is not an absolute path, and relative paths are not permitted.

Additional information: The parameter is incorrect.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.`

Comment: See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx please let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 4):

This is possibly the correct way (didn't test in windows store project). Pay attention to which element added to which parent element and what inner text being assigned to which element, that is where your original codes incorrectly do (I appreciate the effort though) :

```
var existingRoot = dom.DocumentElement;

var newElement = dom.CreateElement("drink");
existingRoot.AppendChild(newElement);

var drinkImageElement = dom.CreateElement("drinkImage");
drinkImageElement.InnerText = "ck.png";
newElement.AppendChild(drinkImageElement);

var drinkTitleElement = dom.CreateElement("drinkTitle");
drinkTitleElement.InnerText = "COKE";
newElement.AppendChild(drinkTitleElement);

var drinkDescriptionElement = dom.CreateElement("drinkDescription");
drinkDescriptionElement.InnerText = "Nothing";
newElement.AppendChild(drinkDescriptionElement);
```

Here is a link to online demo (console based apps) : https://dotnetfiddle.net/oElYWJ

**output :**

```
<drinks>
  <drink>
    <drinkImage>pepsi.png</drinkImage>
    <drinkTitle>PEPSI</drinkTitle>
    <drinkDescription>(1793-1844)</drinkDescription>
  </drink>
  <drink>
    <drinkImage>ck.png</drinkImage>
    <drinkTitle>COKE</drinkTitle>
    <drinkDescription>Nothing</drinkDescription>
  </drink>
</drinks>
```

Comment: nothing happens, have replaced my **if condition code with yours.**

Answer (score 3):

You can't save your XML document here. All files from app package are read-only. You have to save your xml document into localState :

```
    public async Task DoJobAsync()
    {
        XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("favourite//fav.xml");
        xmlDoc.Root.Add(new XElement("drink",
                    new XAttribute("drinkImage", "ck.png"),
                    new XAttribute("drinkTitle", "PEPSI"),
                    new XAttribute("drinkDescription", "NONE")

                ));
        using (var stream = await (await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("fav.xml")).OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            xmlDoc.Save(stream.AsStreamForWrite());
        }
    }
```